# Adding new filed to eloquent Mongodb laravel model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am using Mogodb and eloquent, I have created a model and now I want to add one more field in it.

I have added the new field in the `protected $fillable` array in Moloquent model

I updated the document using update function with $attributes and $id.

But the new filed is not getting updated in MongoDB.

How I can fix this?

Thanks,
Unnikrishnan B.

Comment: are you added the new field in $fillable in model

Comment: @ali - Yes I did but still its not getting updated.